# Sql query with sql subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Hi all I have written the following query to combine the results from 3 tables(`tblQuestions,tblReplies,tblTechnology` and display the required results as follows

```
SELECT tech.DatePosted,
       tech.QuestionID,
       tech.TechnologyName,
       tblr3.TechID,
       tblr3.QuestionTitle,
       tblr3.UserName,
       tblr3.ReplyCount,
       tblr3.viewCount,
       tblr3.date,
       tblr3.RepliedName
FROM   (SELECT tblr1.DatePosted,
               tblr1.QuestionID,
               tblr2.TechID,
               tblr2.QuestionTitle,
               tblr2.UserName,
               tblr2.ReplyCount,
               tblr2.viewCount,
               tblr1.date,
               tblr1.RepliedName
        FROM   (SELECT tblq.DatePosted,
                       tblq.TechID,
                       tblq.QuestionID,
                       tblq.RepliedName,
                       tblq.QuestionTitle,
                       tblq.UserName,
                       tblq.ReplyCount,
                       tblq.viewCount,
                       tblq.date
                FROM   (SELECT q.DatePosted,
                               q.TechID,
                               q.QuestionID,
                               q.QuestionTitle,
                               q.UserName,
                               q.ReplyCount,
                               q.viewCount,
                               r.date,
                               r.UserName AS RepliedName
                        FROM   tblQuestions AS q, tblReplies AS r
                        WHERE  r.QuestionID = q.QuestionID
                               AND r.TechID = q.TechID
                               AND q.TechID = 1) AS tblq,
                                                 (SELECT   r.QuestionID,
                                                           max(r.date) AS PostedDate
                                                  FROM     tblReplies AS r
                                                  GROUP BY QuestionID) AS tblr
                WHERE  tblq.QuestionID = tblr.QuestionID
                       AND tblq.date = tblr.PostedDate) AS tblr1
               RIGHT OUTER JOIN
               (SELECT q.QuestionID,
                       q.TechID,
                       q.UserName,
                       q.viewCount,
                       q.ReplyCount,
                       q.QuestionTitle
                FROM   tblQuestions AS q
                WHERE  q.TechID = 1) AS tblr2
               ON tblr2.QuestionID = tblr1.QuestionID) AS tblr3
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       (SELECT q.QuestionID,
               q.DatePosted,
               t.TechID,
               t.TechName AS TechnologyName
        FROM   tblTechnology AS t, tblQuestions AS q
        WHERE  q.TechID = t.TechID) AS tech
        ON tblr3.TechID = tech.TechID
           AND tblr3.QuestionID = tech.QuestionID
           AND tech.TechID = 1
```

Which gives me the following result as expected but getting `NULL` at some fields where data to be present

[image]

In place of `NULL` i need to pull out some data which is present in `tblQuestions`, also is it possible to reduce the query.

From OPs Comment:

I am trying to pull out the q`uestiontitle,username,questionid from tblquestions` along with `replycount and viewcount` and the latest replys that are posted for that questions based on `QuestionID` and Technology ID from `tblreplys`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this query? Your query is not easy to follow and hard to guess. Can you post sample data and expected results? There might be a simpler way to return expected results and not use so many subqueries

Comment: `rs` you can check my image for what I am trying to achieve

Comment: your image shows expected data, but not any business logic or conditions to apply. Explain your problem and what your trying to achieve with this query.

Comment: `rs` I am trying to pull out the `questiontitle,username,questionid` from `tblquestions` along with `replycount and viewcount` and the latest replys that are posted for that questions based on QuestionID and Technology ID from `tblreplys`

Comment: Off topic: Why are you mixing your join types? Please don't use the `WHERE <join condition>` way , it's confusing, and easier to forget (and therefore end up with cartesian products).

Comment: @Dotnet this would be difficult to debug in its current format.  My suggestion would be to start from the subqueries and work out slowly adding more joins.  This will let you see where the data issue is coming from

Comment: @Dotnet I've added a query below. Can you test it and see if it gets the data you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is basically this:

```
SELECT
    blah
FROM
    (
        (SELECT
            blah
        FROM
            Questions
            INNER JOIN Replies ON QuestionID AND TechID) tblr1
        RIGHT JOIN Questions tblr2 ON QuestionID
    ) tblr3
    LEFT JOIN Technologies ON tblr3.tblr1.QuestionID = Technologies.QuestionID
```

I know that isn't a valid query but bear with me. `tblr1`contains an `INNER JOIN` between questions and answers. However because there are no answers to the `salary` question these records are `NULL`for the `salary`question. The `RIGHT JOIN` to Questions then introduces the `salary` question and that exists in the `tblr3` result set because it is a `RIGHT JOIN` even though `tblr1` is null for this question.

The `LEFT JOIN` then to technologies is based on the `QuestionID` within `tblr3` which is really the `QuestionID` from `tblr1`. From looking at the column list for the `tblr3` sub query, if you change `tblr1.QuestionID` to `tblr2.QuestionID` this will ensure that unanswered questions join on to the `Technology` table

EDIT: I think the following query will give you your results and is much simpler:

```
WITH LatestReplies AS
(
  SELECT
    ReplyID,
    QuestionID,
    ReplyDate,
    UserName,
    Reply
  FROM
    (SELECT
      ReplyID,
      QuestionID,
      ReplyDate,
      UserName,
      Reply,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY QuestionID ORDER BY ReplyDate DESC) ReplyOrder
    FROM
      tblReplies) A
  WHERE
    ReplyOrder = 1
)
SELECT
  tblQuestions.DatePosted,
  tblQuestions.QuestionID,
  tblTechnology.TechnologyName,
  tblQuestions.TechID,
  tblQuestions.QuestionTitle,
  tblQuestions.UserName,
  tblQuestions.ReplyCount,
  tblQuestions.ViewCount,
  LatestReplies.ReplyDate,
  LatestReplies.UserName RepliedName
FROM
  tblQuestions
  LEFT JOIN tblTechnology ON tblQuestions.TechID = tblTechnology.TechID
  LEFT JOIN LatestReplies ON tblQuestions.QuestionID = LatestReplies.QuestionID
```

Comment: @Dotnet this can only give duplicates if `tblQuestions.QuestionID`or `tblTechnology.TechnologyID`do not have a unique constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with the following after all

```
select 
    FI.QuestionID,
    FI.QuestionTitle,
    FI.UserName,
    FI.DatePosted,
    FI.[date],
    FI.RepliedName,
    FI.viewCount,
    FI.ReplyCount,
    FI.ReplyMsg,
    TT.TechID,
    TT.TechName 
from 
    tblTechnology TT,
    (select distinct
        TQ.TechID,
        TQ.QuestionID,
        TQ.QuestionTitle,
        TQ.UserName,
        TQ.DatePosted,
        TR.[date],
        TR.UserName as RepliedName,
        TQ.viewCount,
        TQ.ReplyCount,
        TR.ReplyMsg 
    from  
        tblQuestions TQ 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN tblReplies TR ON 
                TR.TechID=TQ.TechID 
            and TR.QuestionID = TQ.QUESTIONID 
            and TR.[date] in (select 
                                MAX(TR.[date]) 
                            from 
                                tblReplies TR 
                            group by 
                                TR.QuestionID)
    ) FI 
where 
    FI.TechID=TT.TechID 
and TT.TechID=@TechID
```

[image]

Comment: That query has a bug in it though. If Question 1 has two or more answers, and Question two has one or more answer, if any of Question 1's answers have the same [tblReplies.Date] value as the latest anser to Question 2, you will get multiple rows for a Question 1.

Comment: I didn't get multiple rows even if I have more answers for questions

Comment: I think you will if two answers for two different questions have the exact same `[date]` value, provided one of them is the latest answer for its question. I suggest you test that and if I'm wrong then you should be OK. If you only have 3 answers, 1,2 and 3. And two quesitons, 1 and 2. If answers 1 and 2 are for question 1 and answer 3 is for question 2, then you will get duplicates if answer 1 and 3 occrred at the same time. See an example I created: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cd6c6/1 you can see that the latest answer for Q2 occurred at the same time as a non-latest answer to Q1

Comment: Ok as per your query if we have the same reply at a time duplication arise but as I am taking complete time it will have seconds so that duplication didn't arise I think so

Comment: If the traffic on your site is small enough you will probably be OK, it's still a bug and I would expect it to cause an issue in the future. Your call though.